# Js, HTML, and CSS to make matrix rainbow rain not working

Tags: javascript, html, css

https://codepen.io/deathshadow8123/pen/KKNaLXq That is my pen from codepen, however when I create an html doc, and put the js into a  tag and the css into a  tag it doesn't show up on the webpage I also put the   in there. Pls help me I do not know how to make this work. Any ideas?
if you can't access codepen here is my code:

```js
var w = c.width = window.innerWidth,
    h = c.height = window.innerHeight,
    ctx = c.getContext( '2d' ),
    
    opts = {
      
      chars: '\1234567890ìqwertyuiopè+asdfghjklòàù<zxcvbnm,.-|!"£$%&/()=?^QWERTYUIOPé*ASDFGHJKLç°§>ZXCVBNM;:_[]@#€{}'.split(''), // every key in the italian keyboard layout. It sucks, we don't even have a backtick!
      font: '12px monospace',
      charSize: 14,
      lineHeight: 14,
      
      hueSpeed: 1,
      repaintAlpha: .1,
      
      stripesParXxY: .1,
      stripeSpeed: .5,
      beforeSpawning: 50
    },
    
    tick = 0,
    endX = ( w / opts.charSize + 1 ) |0,
    endY = ( h / opts.lineHeight + 1 ) |0,    
    sum = w + h,
    stripes = [];

ctx.font = opts.font;
ctx.fillStyle = '#111';
ctx.fillRect( 0, 0, w, h );

function loop() {
  
  window.requestAnimationFrame( loop );
  
  tick += opts.hueSpeed;
  
  ctx.fillStyle = 'rgba(0,0,0,alp)'.replace( 'alp', opts.repaintAlpha );
  ctx.fillRect( 0, 0, w, h );
  
  stripes.map( function( stripe ){ stripe.step(); } );
}

function Stripe(){
  
  this.reset();
}
Stripe.prototype.reset = function() {
  
  this.x = ( Math.random() * endX ) |0;
  this.y = -Math.random() * opts.beforeSpawning;
}
Stripe.prototype.step = function() {
  
  this.y += opts.stripeSpeed;
  
  drawLetter( this.x, this.y|0 );
  
  if( this.y > endX )
    this.reset();
}

function drawLetter( x, y ){
  
  x *= opts.charSize;
  y *= opts.lineHeight;
  
  ctx.fillStyle = 'hsl(hue,80%,50%)'.replace( 'hue', ( x + y ) / sum * 360 + tick );
  ctx.fillText( opts.chars[ ( Math.random() * opts.chars.length ) |0 ], x, y );
}

for( var i = 0; i < endX*endX * opts.stripesParXxY; ++i )
  stripes.push( new Stripe );

loop();

window.addEventListener( 'resize', function(){
  
  w = c.width = window.innerWidth;
  h = c.height = window.innerHeight;
  ctx.fillStyle = '#111';
  ctx.fillRect( 0, 0, w, h );
  ctx.font = opts.font;
  
  endX = ( w / opts.charSize + 1 ) |0;
  endY = ( h / opts.lineHeight + 1 ) |0;  
  sum = w + h;
  
  stripes.length = 0;
  for( var i = 0; i < endX*endY * opts.stripesParXxY; ++i )
    stripes.push( new Stripe );
})
```

```css
canvas {
  
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<canvas id=c></canvas>
```

Comment: it runs fine on my machine. i got it runnin with vs code

Comment: Weird that, that works for you

Comment: i added some random numbers just to mess around... rando = Math.floor(Math.random() * 66) + 12,

Comment: yea its works fine on chrom fox safari... i didnt change a thing

Comment: I DO have 'prettier' running tho and it might have fixed something.. i'll look

Comment: tell me pls what was fixed if you can.

Comment: Prettier DEFinitely fixed the     <canvas id=c></canvas> to     <canvas id='c'></canvas>. But i switched it back and it still runs

Comment: yea it aint that

Comment: i thought the same about the const c = document.getElementById("c"); but i just ran it first and it worked

Comment: have anything else that was changed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once the [DOM is loaded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9899372/pure-javascript-equivalent-of-jquerys-ready-how-to-call-a-function-when-t), you need to get a reference to your canvas DOM element at the top of your script or load handler function.

```
const c = document.getElementById("c");
```

Also its best to use quotes in your html.

e.g.

```
<canvas id="c"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem of your code is that you have not put your canvas' id inside `""`, putting t
I have seen the code. There is a small error in `html` file and this is the cause of the project not working. It is simple, Just put your canvas id in `""` doublequotes.

```
<canvas id="c"></canvas>
```

Thanks, Hope it helps

Comment: It should not matter a whole lot but I fixed it already, thanks anyway